# Calculating area that polygon occupies within another polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, area

I am using QGIS.

[image]

How do I  calculate the area that polygons (such as those brown and red ones) occupy within the area of that "more pink" polygon?

Comment: A bit unclear, but you can try Overlap Analysis algorithm in the Processing Toolbox. Make sure both layers are in the same CRS and use a projected CRS, so that the calculated areas are meaningful.

Comment: Dissolve brown & red, calculate their area, join attributes by location to the pinkish one.